# How do you stop Eclipse from underlining functions?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-hinting

Is there a way to disable the code-hint underlining in Eclipse?

[image]

I use an eclipse-based IDE for a dynamic language, so it gets annoying at times when it can't discover methods from classes in other folders, and it fills half my screen with distracting yellow lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for "annotations" in the preferences pane. Select "warnings" (if that's what they are) and uncheck the "text" box.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm using CFBuilder, which is built on top of Eclipse. Disabling the Build Automatically didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason methods which were not found are being underlined is because eclipse is automatically building your project as you're editing your code. The easiest way to stop eclipse from underlining methods is to stop the project form building automatically by disabling the option. To do so, deselect the option from the project menu: **Project -> Build Automatically**

The Eclipse Wiki also has alternative ways to [disable autobuilding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_turn_off_autobuilding_of_Java_code?).

Comment: thanks. That will not do it for me, though. It must be my special build of Eclipse.

Comment: That *might* work if you clean the project, which should also clean the warnings and make it start from scratch. It seems a bit persnickety about that sort of thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will also find Syntax Colouring in Eclipse for most languages. You will often find that you can turn on/off underline and strikethrough in these sections.

For example, when viewing PHP files in Eclipse you may find that Parameter Variables are underlined (e.g. variables passed into function). If you find this annoying (like me) then go to Preferences->PHP->Editor->Syntax Colouring, select Parameter variables and untick "underline" on the right. Confusing I know, as underlining is not Syntax Colouring.

[image: Preferences->PHP->Editor->Syntax Colouring]